# Training SVM with images of different categories

Tags: opencv, tensorflow, machine-learning, svm

I am new to machine learning, my aim is to classify traffic/road signs using `SVM`.

**My question is:** Can the training `data set` of `positive` images contains different categories of images?

ex: I want to classify those two type of images to turn `RIGHT`, is it possible ? would be the data still linearly separable?

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kX3OF.jpg)

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qGDBX.jpg)

Comment: SVMs, in their full generality, can be used for [multiclass image classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine#Multiclass_SVM). However, if you _only_ want to use a binary SVM, I think it would depend on how the data are distributed.

Comment: @asfeynman recently i managed to train `One class linear SVM` i used one type of speed limit signs(50) as a positive and all other remaining types of speed limit signs as a negative, the predictions showed really good results, but now sure i want to use `multi class SVM` to solve my problem, the main reason of my question is that i want to reduce my number of classes, so instead of making 1 class for the first image and another 1 class for second image i combine them into 1 class.

Comment: OFF TOPIC: the first image is "dangerous right turn ahead" and the second is "must turn right"

Comment: I know i am just giving an example...